# Search for X amount of occurences within 24-hour Period

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to figure out the best way to search a list of objects for when a certain condition is met within a 24-hour window. I would prefer the 24-hour window be flexible enough that it isn't going by days but just 24-hours. My objects would look like something below.

```
public class Event {
    public DateTime timestamp;
    public string reason;
    public long amount;
}
```

So it would search through this list for when the reason equalled something specific and it there was 10 of these within a 24-hour window it would return a list of those 10 along with any extra ones incase there was more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for ALL 24-hour periods (not just 24 hours prior to now or an arbitrary range), you could do:

```
string reason = "???";

var query = 
    events.Where(ev => ev.Reason = reason)
          .Select(ev => events.Where(ev2 => ev.Reason = reason &&
                                            (ev.timestamp >= ev2.timestamp) &&
                                            (ev.timestamp - ev2.timestamp).TotalHours <= 24))
          .Where(g => g.Count() >= 10);
```

Transation:  for each event, get all events within the 24 hours prior to it, and return all groups where that are at least 10 such events.

Comment: This appears to be the closest in regards of searching for all 24-hour periods, however I do have some issues with this example. ev2 isn't declared so I can't compile it. The other thing I notice is that it doesn't check the event reason to make sure it matches as well, and finally I think it is missing a ) somewhere.

Comment: @7H3LaughingMan I've made those corrections - see if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: @D Stanley, I have a sample program that you can see at the following http://pastebin.com/dEqEtR0P . It works pretty well actually in this example, however trying to figure out if there is a way to prevent the same Event from showing up multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

You can add hours to a `DateTime` instance and then compare your time

```
var startOfWindow = DateTime.Now \\ or however you get your window start
var endOfWindow = startOfWindow.AddHours(24);
var interestingEvents = events
              .Where(e => e.reason == "reason")
              .Where(e=> startOfWindow <= e.timestamp && e.timestamp <= endOfWindow)
              .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ

```
var search = events.Where(ev => ev.reason == "reason" && ev.timestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24));
```

Comment: What if the `timestamp` is in the future?

Comment: Then I would use a start date and end date and compare the ev.timestamp to them

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the trick

```
public IEnumerable<Event> EventsInTimeWindow(
     IEnumerable<Event> events,
     DateTime from,
     DateTime to,  
     string reason, 
     int maxNoOfResults)
{
     return events
         .Where(evt => 
             from <= evt.timestamp && 
             evt.timestamp <= to &&
             evt.reason == reason)
         .Take(maxNoOfResults);
}
```

Use:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
var events = EventsInTimeWindow(someCollection, now.AddHours(-24), now, 15);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants at least a certain number of matches, not a limited number.

Answer (score 0):

Have a method to filter and then return results like:

```
public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvents(List<Event> list, string yourReason)
{
    var query = list.Where(e => e.reason == "your reason" &&
                    e.timestamp >= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24));
    if (query.Count() >= 10)
        return query;
    else
        return null;
}
```